# Missing /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/keyboard

Tags: gconf

I installed gconf-editor and I am not seeing the /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/keyboard. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for 11.10 or 12.04, you most likely need to install `dconf-editor` and look under `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/keyboard` instead, though I'm not sure what exactly you're hoping to find there. You can only alter the plug-in's loading priority, and whether it is active.